# C++/CLI evaluation of native methods in /clr compiled code

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++, clr

Consider the following code that can be compiled wither with or without /clr.... When compiled as a normal program (using Visual Studio 209 or 2017 or 2022) then there are no problems... but as soon as compiled and debugged with /clr problems start [note these "problems" are 100% related to the debugger, not problems with the code....

It appears that *only* the managed debugger is used with the watch and immediate windows, and capabilities associated with native are disabled....

```
class Sample
{
public:
    int Foo();
    static void Bar();
};

//public ref class SampleEmitter
//{
//public:
//    static void Boing() { int x = 1; }
//    static System::String^ Emit(Sample s) 
//    { 
//        s.Foo(); 
//        return s.Foo().ToString();
//    }
//};

int Sample::Foo()
{ 
    return 42;
}
void Sample::Bar() { int x = 1; }


int main()
{
    Sample s;
    std::cout << "Hello World!\n";
}
```

When compiled, a breakpoint can be set on the `cout...`. and `s.Foo()` can be added to wthe watch window... It works :)

Now add /clr... and BOOM, it no longer works... However if one uncommts the `SampleEmitter`, that CAN be wattched....

So how to watch (evaluate) native code when compiled /clr

Comment: Are you sure that your code is compiling when you add /clr ? I tried your example and I had to add /Zc:twoPhase- to allow VS2022 to compile your example. After this the break points were hit as expected

Comment: https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/visualstudio-docs/blob/main/docs/debugger/expressions-in-the-debugger.md

Comment: I  cannot reproduce your problem. Did you change any other options?

Comment: Thanks for the responses: I am OOF today and tomorrow, but quickly: 
USer:Yes, I am compiling with /Zc:twoPhase-). 
MinxinYu: can who post a screen shot? 
Hans: In my reading of that list I did not spot any specific conditions of "works under C++ but gets broken (without changing any code) when switching to C++/CLI (aka /clr)" Will re-review on Friday

Comment: Did you set the debugger type in project-> properties to `Mixed`?

Comment: @MinxinYu-MSFT - Please post as answer... NOTE: this is anot apparently necessary in 2019 nor early 2021....but is important in later 2022.

Answer (score 1):

C++CLI requires Mixed Debugger Type. VS2022 sets Auto as Default. It should work.